# Interpreting Mongo's serverStatus data

Tags: mongodb, health-monitoring

We are in the process of building a monitor program for a server that uses Mongo DB.  Regarding health checks, I see a lot of comments that the "serverStatus" command provides a lot of information, and it looks like it does.  What I am looking for is a discussion of interpreting this data and trends over time of the data returned.

Does anyone have a link to such a reference?  I know I am a bit far afield from straight programming questions;  maybe StackOverflow is the wrong forum; in such a case, can you point me in the right direction?

(Best Wishes for 2013 to all the code slingers out there!)

CVSDave

Answer (score 2):

Indeed `serverStatus` is the most complete native metrics-gathering command provided by MongoDB. It returns a document with statistics from most of the key metrics you should track in order to properly monitor your MongoDB cluster(s): connections, operations, journaling, background flushing, locking, cursors, memory, asserts...
You can find the full list of metrics it returns [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#output).

To answer your question, [this post](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-mongodb-performance-metrics-wiredtiger/) details how to properly interpret these statistics (from this `serverStatus` command but also from `dbStats` and `replSetGetStatus`), how to correlate them, what values they should have, and the thresholds they shouldn't exceed over time. (The post is for the WiredTiger storage engine, but there is also [one dedicated to MMAPv1](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-mongodb-performance-metrics-mmap/)).

Answer (score 1):

There is a page in the documentation that covers the output of the Server Status command.
You can find it [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/).  The page is not really a discussion on trends over time, so it is not exactly what you are looking for but it should cover all the output values and their meanings.

You can check out MMS, which leverages much of the information in the Server Status output [here](http://mms.10gen.com).  MMs also measures this activity against time.

For a more general overview of monitoring MongoDB databases, you can check out [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/) in the documentation.  This also has links to other third party monitoring solutions.